# delphi 2009 compile packages

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-2009, package

i truly don't get it.

trying to recompile the qr5 packages, and is impossible with this Delphi.

build the QR5Run_Rad6.bpl, everything is fine.

when i install QR5Design_RAD6.bpl an error message appears

"its not possible to run the program since qr5run_rad.bpl is missing in your computer. try again installing your program to solve this problem."

just did!

clean build compile doesn't work in any order. closed the ide and reopened , still doesn't work.

what else is left?

clean all related dcp and bpl

Comment: NEVER COMPILE AND INSTALL PACKAGES MANUALLY WITHIN DELPHI! USE DELPHI-PI!!! http://code.google.com/p/delphipi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QR5Design_RAD6.bpl <> qr5run_rad.bpl

And more importantly, the qr5run_rad.bpl needs to be found on the systempath in order for the IDE to find it so it can be used by the design time package.

In other words: you need to build the qr5run_rad.bpl as well as the QR5Design_RAD6.bpl. And you need to make sure that the qr5run_rad.bpl ends up in a folder that is on your system path, not just any old folder where you have the sources and/or dcu's.

Comment: sound far fetch that it MUST be system32. there must be a definition field something like tools->options->environment options -> Delphi options -> library - win32 -> library path

Comment: after restarting the delphi should a suggestion fix that was the same as this answer. Thanks.

Comment: The Delphi library search path is only to find sources and dcu's. Not to find of dll's (which is what bpl's ultimately are). The runtime bpl is loaded like any other dll and must therefore exist on the path that is searched by Windows to find executables and dll's: the Windows' system path. And yes you can change the Windows' system path. There is an option somewhere in your "My Computer|Properties|" and then some Advanced button. But it is probably easier to put the runtime bpl's in the default Delphi output folder for bpl's.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Marjan wrote:

Windows uses [these places](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx) when looking for a DLL (or BPL, which is a DLL):

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The system directory. Use the [GetSystemDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373.aspx) function to get the path of this directory.
3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
4. The Windows directory. Use the [GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454.aspx) function to get the path of this directory.
5. The current directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

Delphi puts BPL files in a directory like `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Bpl` which it adds to your PATH when Delphi is installed. For Delphi 2009, that Path would probably be `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl` on a Windows XP machine.

--jeroen